# Is TV Box infected?

Tags: upnp, iptv

I incidentally noticed strange firewall log entries like the following on my computer:

```
Apr  1 22:17:56 slavic-probook kernel: [23623.091873] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=d0:57:7b:60:3a:6a:18:b8:1f:27:ed:06:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.65 DST=192.168.1.70 LEN=323 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=64 ID=39529 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49952 LEN=303 
Apr  1 22:17:57 slavic-probook kernel: [23624.092666] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=d0:57:7b:60:3a:6a:18:b8:1f:27:ed:06:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.65 DST=192.168.1.70 LEN=323 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=64 ID=39622 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49952 LEN=303 
Apr  1 22:17:58 slavic-probook kernel: [23625.094162] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=d0:57:7b:60:3a:6a:18:b8:1f:27:ed:06:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.65 DST=192.168.1.70 LEN=323 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=64 ID=40181 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49952 LEN=303 
Apr  1 22:17:59 slavic-probook kernel: [23626.094239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=d0:57:7b:60:3a:6a:18:b8:1f:27:ed:06:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.65 DST=192.168.1.70 LEN=323 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xA0 TTL=64 ID=40237 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=49952 LEN=303
```

The device with the SRC IP address is a Telus DVR box, connected to the Smart TV. I see no reason why a TV Box should attempt to send messages to computers on the network, especially on random ports, as it seems to be the case from the log.

Am I right in concluding that the DVR box has been infected and is running some vulnerability scanner?

**UPDATE 1**

Because I wanted to get a full picture, not just the firewall blocked traffic, I went ahead and performed a few tcpdump-s on my computer, related to the host in question: `tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n  "src host 192.168.1.65 or dst host 192.168.1.65"` (note that, although I'm listening on a wifi interface, the TV box itself is on Ethernet, if it matter)

The result was a bunch of multicast requests like these:

```
01:59:17.410558 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 1, id 9041, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 564)
    192.168.1.65.40106 > 239.255.255.250.8082: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 536
01:59:20.482689 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 1, id 11391, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 564)
    192.168.1.65.40106 > 239.255.255.250.8082: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 536
01:59:23.350033 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 1, id 14259, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 564)
    192.168.1.65.40106 > 239.255.255.250.8082: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 536
01:59:26.421815 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 1, id 16051, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 564)
    192.168.1.65.40106 > 239.255.255.250.8082: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 536
01:59:29.494329 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 1, id 17699, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 564)
    192.168.1.65.40106 > 239.255.255.250.8082: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 536
```

each of the messages bearing content like this:

```
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
x-type: dvr
x-filter: f0e4ba33-5680-459b-8c3d-a4fdeffdb2f9
x-lastUserActivity: 4/2/2018 7:26:29 AM
x-location: http://192.168.1.65:8080/dvrfs/info.xml
x-device: 0d90b7cc-3fc2-4890-b2b9-8f7026732fd6
x-debug: http://192.168.1.65:8080

<node count='7102'><activities><schedver dver='3' ver='57' pendcap='True' /><x/><p15n stamp='08D514D5EC333DF818B81F27ED06'/><recordver ver='46' verid='355872864' size='962072674304' free='952610324480' /><x/></activities></node>
```

then once in a while the familiar, firewall-blocked requests:

```
02:02:28.005207 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 64, id 34066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 323)
    192.168.1.65.1900 > 192.168.1.70.53280: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 295
02:02:28.900119 IP (tos 0xa0, ttl 64, id 34258, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 323)
    192.168.1.65.1900 > 192.168.1.70.53280: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 295
```

with content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.65:56790/dd.xml
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800
EXT:
BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 1
SERVER: Linux/2.6 UPnP/1.1 quick_ssdp/1.1
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
USN: uuid:0d90b7cc-3fc2-4890-b2b9-8f7026732fd6::urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
```

This would suggest to me a broken SSDP implementation, but any input from knowledgeable people could shed light on the situation.

**UPDATE 2**

I found the culprit for the group of messages blocked by the firewall (192.168.1.65:1900 -> my.computer:random_port). Google Chrome kept multicasting SSDP discovery requests every minute or so. Due to the way it's coded, these requests use a seemingly random ports and thus, when a legitimate response came from the TV Box, it got blocked.

This clarifies the first group of messages. I'd like to still know what causes the second group.

Comment: **192.168.1.70** is an intranet address it doesn’t exist outside of your network

Comment: “Am I right in concluding that the DVR box has been infected and is running some vulnerability scanner?” - No; You wouldn’t be right to assume this.

Comment: @Ramhound yes - that is indeed an intranet address. How is that conflicting with my hypothesis?

Comment: UDP 1900 is or should be [SSDP aka UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). Is there anything on your machine that would be sending UPnP requests? Note the requests go to multicast, which might explain your firewall not recognizing these replies as related (assuming it's set to accept related, as is usual).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 wouldn't the machine in this case be sending to 1900 too instead of seemingly random ports?

Comment: @Slavic - At the very worst you would be attacking yourself, but that isn't happening.

Comment: Your machine would be sending requests _from_ random, transient ports to 1900 (not blocked and not logged) then getting responses _to_ those ports.

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening for a multitude of reasons, so don't jump to conclusions too fast. Many internet-enabled devices perform scans of a network on a periodical basis, or when certain conditions are met. As the former does not seem to be the case, the DVR may have detected a change in the network, such as as a new device sending packets, a change in network security in which the pre-shared key remained the same (i.e. WPA to WPA2), or even a difference in protocol versions triggered by an automatic update of the router. These are just a few reasons why the device would perform this action.

My advice to you is to run a network scan. You can do this using a variety of tools, such as [NMap](https://nmap.org), a very popular free network mapping tool which offers both command-line and graphical options. NMap and most other network mapping tools provide lots of detail on the mapped devices, so I would suggest mapping out your network and rooting out any suspicious IP addresses. With the modern abundance of ISP-enforced port filtering and "enabled-by-default" network-wide firewalls, most common attacks now come from inside the network (e.g. a nearby attacker has gained access to your Wi-Fi network, and has logged in and launched malicious attacks). Therefore, mapping your network is going to be your best bet for finding malicious entities. You could also employ a network intrusion detection system such as [Snort](https://www.snort.org/). Provided you are using a wireless network, the first logical step would be to change the pre-shared key (or "password") to a strong, preferably randomly-generated key. As previously mentioned, most attacks come from within your network, so unless the attacker has persistent access to a device on your network and/or has physical access to your router, this will stop many attackers, at least temporarily.

Comment: I should add that the DVR keeps doing this continually. About 15 times a minute. Since forever. Also, note the different ports.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - what am I trying to find out with a network scan?

Comment: Your Q shows 4 every 2 minutes, not 15 per minute.

Comment: @Slavic sorry if that wasn't clear. The purpose of a network scan would be to find any potential attackers on the network.

Comment: As you can see from updates and comments I've made quite some progress in identifying the weird traffic. I still don't know why the dvr multicasts on port 8082 (from seemingly random ports), but at least I'm positive it's not an infection, but something like a weird [mis]configuration.

Comment: @Slavic The reasoning may be described in documentation (manuals, technical papers, etc.) of the TV box. Or, you could always attempt to gain command-line access and simply run `netstat -tulpn` to figure out what programs are running on what ports.